# Facebook Like Box not working for Facebook profile URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've found that the Like Box app for Facebook will not recognise certain pages and profiles. I thought it might have a been a privacy issue buts its not. As it shows pages I have no affiliation with fine enough. But My own personal page and my clients page will show.

clients page is www.facebook.com/scottish.p.drumming

All  I see is this error message:

```
There was an error fetching the like box for the specified page.
```

Comment: That's a user profile, the like box is for pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Igy is right, the like box can only be used on a facebook page and not on a facebook user profile.

One option would be to convert your user profile to a facebook page. This can be done following the steps on the link below:

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=116067818477568#How-do-I-convert-my-personal-account-to-a-Facebook-Page?

When this is in place you can then visit the [plugins page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) and get the code needed for your like box